# Is it OK to link to a JQuery plugin hosted on another site?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope, virus

My site keeps getting viruses. Webmaster tools always points to the Jquery [Isotope plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) I downloaded (and paid for). Whenever I remove it, and download it again the site works, but a week down the track it gets black listed again.

To remedy this I have linked directly to the same source code that the Isotope site uses. eg:

`<script src="http://isotope.metafizzy.co/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>`

Is this OK? Will I run into any issues becuase of this?

Comment: If that is a CDN or they have allowed their script to be used like that then there isn't any harm doing that

Comment: Thanks Hanky, but whats a CDN?

Comment: If you **trust** `isotope.metafizzy.co` owners - then use it, otherwise - no

Comment: if possible dont use. because in case of that server down your code also keep down

Comment: @zerkms thanks, is there any reason not to trust them? (I guess they could mess around with their code if they wanted to)

Comment: @MeltingDog: I don't know them. But just keep in mind that they may steal everything your users put and get on your site if they wanted

Comment: You should NOT link to files on another site unless you have express permission to do so (you're costing them bandwidth usage) and even then only if you know the other site to be at least as reliable as your own site.  Ideally, if you don't want to use your own site for hosting it, you would link to a public CDN.  If you don't know what a CDN is, then you need to do some Google searching and learn.  There are a number of public CDNs that offer their services for free (Google and Microsoft each run one).  But, you'll have to find one that hosts isotope.

Comment: @jfriend00 awesome thanks for that advice. I found this and am now using it http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!isotope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll turn my comment into an answer since it led you to a solution.

You should NOT link to files on another site unless you have express permission to do so (you're costing them bandwidth usage) and even then only if you know the other site to be at least as reliable as your own site. Ideally, if you don't want to use your own site for hosting it, you would link to a public CDN. If you don't know what a CDN is, then you need to do some Google searching and learn. There are a number of public CDNs that offer their services for free (Google and Microsoft each run one). But, you'll have to find one that hosts isotope.

Answer (score 1):

I found this public CDN entry

//cdn.jsdelivr.net/isotope/1.5.25/jquery.isotope.min.js

//cdn.jsdelivr.net/isotope/1.5.25/jquery.isotope.js

from the public cdn: jsdelivr.com